# git rebase -i HEAD~N returns more than N commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

Here is my git command:

`git rebase -i HEAD~2`

I would expect to see the 2 most recent commits but I see this instead:

[image]

I also want to mention that while I have been attempting to squash certain commits, I consistently running into merge conflicts. I'm getting the feeling that these issues might be related.

I'm a bit of a git noob so any help would be much appreciated.

`git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate`:
[image]

Commit Chain:

[image]

Comment: Did you squash commits?

Comment: What does `git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate` show? Seems like there is a merge involved here somewhere, with commits containing the same changes showing up on both sides of the merge.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was going to ask. Maybe `git log -n 10 --graph --all --oneline` to keep it short

Comment: I included it in my original post. I did rebase to master but I don't know why my commits on my test branch "duplicate" when I rebased.

Comment: Yeah, you're trying to do an interactive rebase thru a merge commit, that's kind of incoherent and that's why you're getting all those extra commits from the other side of the merge.

Comment: Can you explain what your actual goal is? Never mind the interactive rebase, what would you _really_ like to accomplish?

Comment: Okay so if you go back 2 commits on the left, you'll automatically get those on the right because of the merge.

Comment: @matt : My ultimate goal is to squash a ton of my noisy commits. This merge conflict is getting in the way. I would like to understand what I did wrong to avoid this in the future. I ended up rebasing my PR to master instead of a colleagues branch and then ran `git pull` which may have caused this.

Comment: Okay I get this a lot. If your team squashes a lot, you'll get this often, because if you're working on their "old" "original" commit and they then squash their next commit, git creates a whole new commit instead of changing that "old" commit. They force push that und after pulling their revision, you'll get a conflict, because you're "old" "original" commit and not the way anymore, they worked on. My solution was to remember my changes (stash or creating a patch) and reset hard to where it was all okay and apply the changes.

Comment: @JanosVinceller: Thanks for this explanation. I'm not quite sure how to get back to that previous state. I uploaded a picture of my commit thread on my PR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merge commits have more than one parent commit. `~` indicates the *first parent* of a commit. That is the left hand side of your graph. ***`~` only follows the first parents***. `HEAD~2` asks for the first grandparent.

`~` is a good way to move through history skipping over merged branches.

```
* HEAD
|\
| *
| *
| *
| *
* | HEAD~1
|/
* HEAD~2
|\
| *
| *
|/
* HEAD~3
```

`git rebase -i HEAD~2` is really `git rebase -i HEAD~2..HEAD` so you're going to get all the commits reachable from `HEAD` excluding all the commits reachable from `HEAD~2`. That means `HEAD`, `HEAD~1`, and all the commits in the side branch.

`^` is for selecting parents. `HEAD^` is the first parent, same as `HEAD~`. `HEAD^2` selects the second parent, which is the first commit in the branch.

`^` and `~` can be chained. If you want just two commits on the side branch, that's `git rebase -i HEAD^2~2`. `HEAD^2` selects the second parent of HEAD. So `HEAD^2~2` is the first grandparent of the second parent of HEAD. It's easier with an illustration.

```
* HEAD
|\
| * HEAD^2
| * HEAD^2~ also HEAD^2^
| * HEAD^2~2 also HEAD^2^^
| * HEAD^2~3 also HEAD^2^^^
* | HEAD~1 also HEAD^1
|/
* HEAD~2 also HEAD^1~
|\
| *
| *
|/
* HEAD~3
```

Confused? That's ok. Rather than messing with all this, it's often easier to just rebase back to the branch you merged off of and leave the extra commits as `pick`.

```
git rebase -i main
```

See [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for more.

Comment: In this case it looks different. Because there's a commit on the long left line. If looks like `HEAD~1` is probably one commit on the right side of the branch and `HEAD~2` would be the left side commit. Look at the ids of the `git rebase` and the ids from the `git log`.

Comment: @JanosVinceller Thanks, I fixed the illustrations.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess I'm still a bit confused. I have a total of 76 commits on my test-branch but this "rebase issue" doesn't seem to include all of that. Ideally, I'd be able to revert back to a "pre-merge state", then incorporate these changes again and then squash these commits.

Comment: @madsthaks You said you only wanted 2 commits. I don't know what the 76 others are about or which merge you want to revert before, sorry.

Comment: I see, that's totally fair. there were some conversation about the broader issue.

Comment: @madsthaks I think it best if you asked that as another question.

Comment: Will do. I did have one question about `git rebase -i main`. Will that take me to commit `bb7a0...`?

Comment: @madsthaks Since bb7a0 is your HEAD, `git rebase -i main` will do `main..HEAD` or all the commits reachable from HEAD minus all the commits reachable from main. That is *probably* what you want, but I can't say for sure. `git log --graph --decorate --oneline main..HEAD` will tell you.